# System.Collections.Immutable.dll is being replaced from Microsoft.Net.Compilers package

Tags: c#, .net, dll, bamboo

I have referenced `system.collections.immutable.dll` from the nuget package and I also have the nuget package installed for `Microsoft.Net.Compilers`. Everything works fine in my local but when I push my code to bamboo, in the runtime I get `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

When I checked logs on bamboo when it generates the artifacts, I can see that initially it copied the correct dll here:

`build    04-Apr-2019 03:20:33      Copying file from "E:\agt01\ENS-EB580-JOB1\Bin\Packages\System.Collections.Immutable.1.5.0\lib\netstandard1.0\System.Collections.Immutable.dll" to "E:\agt01\ENS-EB580-JOB1\Binaries\Release\\temp\Web\_PublishedWebsites\MyService\bin\System.Collections.Immutable.dll".`

but then at some point, it replaced this dll with this:
`build    04-Apr-2019 03:20:33      Copying file from "E:\agt01\ENS-EB580-JOB1\Bin\Packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\tools\System.Collections.Immutable.dll" to "E:\agt01\ENS-EB580-JOB1\Binaries\Release\\temp\Web\_PublishedWebsites\MyService\bin\System.Collections.Immutable.dll".`

How can I make sure that bamboo does not replace this dll and just uses it from the nuget package installed?

Update: Update: I upgraded the `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` nuget package as suggested here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12255#issuecomment-248588545, but now I am getting this error on bamboo:

`E:\agt01\ENS-EB580-BEQI\TeamBuildTypes\BambooBuild.proj(226,2): error MSB3073: The command "XCOPY "E:\agt01\ENS-EB580-BEQI\..\AWInstaller\Binaries\roslyn\*.*" "E:\agt01\ENS-EB580-BEQI\..\AWInstaller\My Project\Source Program Files\My Release\My Service\bin\roslyn\*.*" /y /e" exited with code 4.`

Comment: An error code 4 from XCOPY suggests invalid arguments. Indeed, you don't normally provide a wildcard mask for the copy target to that command.

Comment: is it something on bamboo I need to check. Sorry not familiar with bamboo so checking?

Comment: This appears to be a post-build command, but I don't know off hand who (what part of the tool chain) created it - but it does look wrong to me.

Comment: okay, in my csproj file I do not see any post build events, I may have to check with the bamboo plan in that case.

Comment: this is what the failing xcopy command looks like in bamboo project: <Exec Command="XCOPY &quot;$(myinstaller)\Binaries\roslyn\*.*&quot; &quot;$(myinstaller)\My Project\Source Program Files\My Release\My Service\bin\roslyn\*.*&quot; /y /e" />

Comment: let me know if you see something suspicious here. Thanks.

Comment: I would try it without the trailing `*.*`.

Comment: okay, so I will remove ```*.*``` and try it out.

Comment: I think something went wrong while pasting the command last time. It is: ```<Exec Command="XCOPY &quot;$(awinstaller)\Binaries\roslyn\*.*&quot; &quot;$(awinstaller)\ENS V2\Source Program Files\AirWatch Current Release\Email Notification Service\bin\roslyn\*.*&quot; /y /e" />```

Comment: so should I try: ```<Exec Command="XCOPY &quot;$(awinstaller)\Binaries\roslyn\*.*&quot; &quot;$(awinstaller)\ENS V2\Source Program Files\AirWatch Current Release\Email Notification Service\bin\roslyn\&quot; /y /e" />``` please bear with me here :)

Comment: After it fails, what happens if you run this from a command prompt? - I assume you can figure out how to manually supply the parts that the build system provides.

Comment: actually this build is setup on bamboo server and not in my local so can't run it through command prompt unfortunately.